# Chrome Webstore - Package is in valid. Details: 'Could not unzip extension'

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have build a packaged app and deployed it Chrome Webstore. It correctly uploaded the package and has red the manifest of the zip file. When installing the extension unpacked it also works perfectly. Now after my app was published to the Chrome Store, whenever I or anyone else tries to install it (no matter what system), one gets a Package is in valid. Details: 'Could not unzip extension' from Chrome and that's it. I've catched the file CRX File Chrome is downloading and tries to install and tried to install it locally via drag'n'drop on Chrome getting the same message. Unpacking the file and trying to install as an unpacked extension reveals the _metadata folder to be an issue (Mac?). Removing the folder let's me correctly install the extension (unpacked).

Trying to generate a CRX by myself using Chrome generates a valid CRX that I can install without any issues. The only (quick) difference I can see from my CRX to the one from Chrome Webstore is that weird _metadata folder..

I am trying this on latest Chrome Stable (36x.) as well as on Chrome Canary with same results.

I am really lost having searched the web for solutions without success. All issues mentioned (issues with filenames or root folder etc.) don't work for me as my zip file has none of those issues. The CRX is created from the WebStore so I am really lost what I can do about it?

The App is called "Gravit" in Webstore if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: You should probably post this as a support request in chromium-apps Google Group.

Comment: We've filed https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402278 to track this issue.

Comment: I did also post in chromium-apps group but didn't receive any feedback there

Comment: @sowbug thanks but anyway, how can I put my app correctly in the store now so users can install it? Other vendors' app work fine when downloading and installing them so what shell I do? thanks!!